# Am I using fgetc correctly?

Tags: php, javascript, html

This is my PHP:

```
  $file = fopen("1stock.js", "c+");
  $number = fseek($file, 20, SEEK_CUR);
  $fh = fgetc($number);
  fwrite($file, $fh -1);
```

My 20th character is a number I want to do that `number - 1`when the php file loads. Why is this not working?

I am also looking to do this for multiple other positions on a .js file, that looks a bit like this:

```
var item1_stockS = 5  //20th character including space.
var item1_stockM = 8
var item1_stockL = 3
```

I have a HTML form that looks like this:

```
<form action="stock.php" method="post">

Item1 S:<input value="remove" name="remove1S" type="submit" /> <br/> <script type="text/javascript">document.write(item1_stockS);</script><br/>

Item1 M:<input value="remove" name="remove1M" type="submit" /> <br/> <script type="text/javascript">document.write(item1_stockM);</script> <br/>

Item1 L:<input value="remove" name="remove1L" type="submit" /><br/> <script type="text/javascript">document.write(item1_stockL);</script> <br/>
```

So that when you click on one of the button it removes 1 item from the corresponding stock number.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `fgetc` the current position in the file is advanced one step, so when you write you write to *after* where the number is. You have to seek one step backwards before writing.

Also, be careful if the value is zero, as then you will write `-1` which is two characters and will overwrite the newline after the digit.

The problem you have is that the argument to the `fgetc` function should be the *file handle*. See the [`fgetc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetc.php) documentation!

Comment: I am getting this warning: "Warning: fgetc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in /home/content/57/9770557/html/stock.php on line 5"

Comment: @user2768038 That piece of information should have gone in the question, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: @user2768038 And I've also updated my answer with why you get that problem, and with a hint of what you should do in the future with similar problems.

Comment: I am really sorry! Like this? `$fh = fgetc(fseek($file, 60, SEEK_CUR));`

Comment: @user2768038 No, like `$char = fgetc($file); fseek($file, -1, SEEK_CUR);`

Comment: Doesn't that seek the -1 character? I want to go to the 20th character which is 5 and change it to 4 by `fseek($file, 20, SEEK_CUR) -1`